Convert IEEE Float hex string to an Excel VBA Single (float)
I have an input string read from a device which is an ASCII Hex representation of a 32-bit floating point value.

e.g. "4048f5c3"   (--> 3.14)

My question is how can I turn that into a Single variable (32-bit floating point) for calculations in my Excel VBA application?
I can easily convert the string to 32-bit Long (with 32-bit floating point binary representation).  That's only useful if it were a step toward a Single.
Dim strIeee754 As String
Dim lLong As Long
Dim sSingle as Single

strIeee754 = "4048f5c3"
lLong = Val("&H" & "4048f5c3")        'as an integer 1,078,523,331

I can also use bitwise functions to extract the components (sign, exponent, and mantissa).  Again, only useful if steps toward building a Single.
I got this idea from stackoverflow 9431346 to forceably copy the bit pattern from the Long (above) into a Single.  The lines are in my Excel Sheet1 module.
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
...
CopyMemory sSingle, lLong, 4

But the declaration caused the message Compile error:  Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and Declare statements not allowed as Public members of object modules
Any help toward my goal appreciated.

Thanks @rotabor , but I removed Public and got the same error.  I also found another idea in stackoverflow 74373610 (using LAMBDA functions in Excel's Name Manager), but I get a "name error" and can't see my flaw.  That might not help anyway as I want to convert in the VBA calculations prior to filling a cell with the result.

It seems you put this declaration in workbook, worksheet or form module (object module). You can put it in the project module only.

You may be confused about VBA data types (or I may be confused about what you really want). You seem to be showing a desired result with a precision of ten digits. But you are asking to convert your Hex value to a Single which only has a precision of seven (7) digits. To convert to a Single, use the same technique as you show:  CSng("&H" & "4048f5c3") => 1.078523E+09 

@RonRosenfeld CSng("&H" & "4048f5c3") converts the argument to the integer type number then to the single. But OP needs to get the single from its bit representation which is not the same you suggested.

@rotabor Thank you for clarifying. It seems I was confused and overlooked the 3.14 which is the result he really wanted.

Put everything in a standard module:
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Function CToSng(lLong As Long) As Single
    Dim sSingle As Single
    CopyMemory sSingle, lLong, 4
    CToSng = sSingle
End Function

Sub TestConv()
    Dim strIeee754 As String
    Dim lLong As Long
    strIeee754 = "4048f5c3"
    lLong = Val("&H" & strIeee754)
    Debug.Print CToSng(lLong)
End Sub


Perfect & worked!  I suspected it might have to do with scope and access to external libraries.  I need to work on my understanding of that.  Thanks very much!

Here is the native VBA code to convert float bits expressed by the hex string to the float:
Option Explicit

Function Bits2Float(s As String) As Single
  Dim a As LongLong, b As Boolean
  If Len(s) = 8 And Left$(s, 1) > "7" Then
    b = True
    s = (CInt("&H" & Left$(s, 1)) - 8) & Mid$(s, 2)
  End If
  a = CLngLng("&H" & s)
  Bits2Float = (a And 8388607 Or 8388608) * 2 ^ ((a \ 8388608 And 255) - 150)
  If b Then Bits2Float = -Bits2Float
End Function

Sub test()
  Debug.Print Bits2Float("4048f5c3")
End Sub


3.14


You know your bits - thanks I'll have to try this solution as well.
